# How can I check if a value already exists in a ListBox?

Tags: c#

I want to check the value of a possible entry before I add it to the `ListBox`.

I have `TextBox` which contains the possible entry value.

So I want check if the `ListBox` already contains the value.

- If this value is already inserted: **DON'T** add it.
- If not: Add it.

Comment: Have you searched or tried something? This is normal to add in your question.

Comment: Did you try running Find on the list box or looping and comparing through the items in the list box?

Comment: Sorry guys I'm new in Programming so I don't know much about code in `C#`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!listBoxInstance.Items.Contains("some text")) // case sensitive is not important
            listBoxInstance.Items.Add("some text");
if (!listBoxInstance.Items.Contains("some text".ToLower())) // case sensitive is important  
            listBoxInstance.Items.Add("some text".ToLower());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use linq,

```
bool a = listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().Any(x => x == "some text"); // If any of listbox1 items contains some text it will return true.
if (a) // then here we can decide if we should add it or inform user
{
    MessageBox.Show("Already have it"); // inform
}
else
{
    listBox1.Items.Add("some text"); // add to listbox
}
```

Hope helps,

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the items in you list with the value you are looking for. You can cast the item to String.

```
if (this.listBox1.Items.Contains("123"))
{
   //Do something
}

//Or if you have to compare complex values (regex)
foreach (String item in this.listBox1.Items)
{
   if(item == "123")
   {
      //Do something...
      break;
   }
}
```